# Многоуровневая динамическая маршрутизация в angular

Tags: angular2, angular, маршрутизация, angular-routing

возник вопрос с которым не могу разобраться. Возникла идея создать сайт каталог, в целом сайт получился, но вот не могу решить проблему с роутингом. Хотелось бы засунуть в ссылку всю иерархию категорий и подкатегории, может быть до пяти уровней. Есть допустим такая иерархия:

Курьер

- курьер на велосипеде

-- курьер на временную работу

--- курьер на час

Уборщик

- уборка квартир

-- уборка 1-й комноты

...

Соответственно url должен получиться если мы в последней категории что-то вроде такого

example.com/kurier/kurier-na-velosipede/kurier-vremenno/na-chas

Такое вообще возможно сделать на angular, если так возможно у когото найдется пример router файла. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: не стоит задавать вопрос в таком стиле _Такое вообще возможно сделать на angular_, потому что вряд тебя устроит простой ответ _да_, или что-то в этом духе :) у тебя простая иерархия состоящая из разных параметров. Каждый роут с параметром будет слинкован с 1 компонентов, что-то в виде `:profession -> ProfessionComponent` (где _:profession_ это курьер или уборщик, вместо _prefession_ можешь выбрать любое другое слово), и также вниз `:service -> ServiceComponent`, в итоге должно получиться что-то вроде `:prefession/:service/:service-type/:...` (названия параметров не знаю как назвать по другому)

Comment: Понял, то есть просто с children ничего другого - думал есть более изысканный метод, но в целом вы ответили очень четко на мой вопрос. Спасибо